# Shell script to find & replace value in xml

Tags: xml, shell, scripting, sed, awk

I have a xml config file called config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
   <server-ip>192.168.1.45</server-ip>
   <server-port>1209</server-port>
   <repository-temp-path>/home/john</repository-temp-path>
</config>
```

I have a shell script to configure the values of "server-ip", "server-port" and "import-path" with $1,$2,$3:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -ne 3 ];then
echo "usage: argument 1:IP_Address 2:Server_PORT 3:Temp_PATH"
exit 1
fi
IP=$1
PORT=$2
DIRT=$3

echo "Change values in config.xml..."

sed "s/<server-ip>.*<\/server-ip>/<server-ip>$IP<\/server-ip>/;s/<server-port>.*<\/server-port>/<server-port>$PORT<\/server-port>/;s/<repository-temp-path>.*<\/repository-temp-path>/<repository-temp-path>$DIRT<\/repository-temp-path>/" config.xml > config2.xml

echo "Done."
```

But it only works for the "**$ ./abc.sh a b c**", and not work for "**$ ./abc.sh 192.168.1.6 9909 /home/bbb**".... can you help to get it working and end up with a better solution?

Comment: XSLT would be a much better approach for this.  Is something like xsltproc not available?

Comment: I found it works with two back slash: "$ ./abc.sh 192.168.1.6 9909 \\/home\\/bbb", but still not work with: "$ ./abc.sh 192.168.1.6 9909 $HOME\\/bbb"

Comment: @ziesemer, yes, but I'm not familiar with it. Could you provide the .xsl? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -ne 3 ];then
echo "usage: argument 1:IP_Address 2:Server_PORT 3:Temp_PATH"
exit 1
fi
IP=$1
PORT=$2
DIRT=$3

echo "Change values in config.xml..."

cat <<EOF >config2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
   <server-ip>${IP}</server-ip>
   <server-port>${PORT}</server-port>
   <repository-temp-path>${DIRT}</repository-temp-path>
</config>
EOF  

echo "Done."
```

Answer (score 2):

XML + shell = [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -u /config/server-ip -v 192.168.1.6 -u /config/server-port -v 9909 -u /config/repository-temp-path -v /home/bbb input.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <server-ip>192.168.1.6</server-ip>
  <server-port>9909</server-port>
  <repository-temp-path>/home/bbb</repository-temp-path>
</config>
```

Comment: for OS X users: `brew install xmlstarlet`

Answer (score 0):

The slashes in /home/bbb are throwing it off (I assume you ran into the same problem I did, since you didn't say *why* it ain't working).

You could escape the slashes first if you're confident of the input. Might be better to fire up perl, ruby, etc for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would really suggest using something like xmlstarlet. (http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) To the original question, the periods and '/' are getting substituted into the sed command. They need to be escaped but you can't possibly know if they are going to exist or not. I will look a little more into it, but use xmlstarlet, or another tool besides sed meant for xml, if you can.